# How to join two mysql querys from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two independents querys:

Query 1 (This query get all gallery from my table) :

```
$showgallerys = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM canais");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($showgallerys)) {
echo '<div class="canal-nome">'.$row['nome'].'</div>;
```

Query 2 (This query count numbers of photos per category):

```
$q="SELECT categoria, COUNT(titulo) FROM galerias GROUP BY categoria ";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$q);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
 echo '
('. $row['COUNT(titulo)'] .')';
}
```

I need to show the name of the gallery (query 1) with the numbers of photos (query 2)

like this **Gallery name (30)**

This the structure of first table (called **canais**):

```
  id | nome            | htd     | imagem   | thumb    |
   1 | Gallery Nature  | nature  | face.jpg | thumb.jg | 
   2 | Gallery Peoples | people  | face.jpg | thumb.jg | 
   3 | Gallery Animals | animal  | face.jpg | thumb.jg |
```

This the structure of second table (called **galerias**)

```
  id | titulo       | foto    | thumb           | data    | categoria |
  1  | Sun          | sun.jpg | sun-thumb.jpg   | now     | nature    |
  2  | Moon         | mon.jpg | mon-thumb.jpg   | now     | nature    |
  3  | Tree         | tree.jpg| tre-thumb.jpg   | now     | nature    |
  4  | Woman        | wman.jpg| wman-thumb.jpg  | now     | people    |
  5  | Girl         | gran.jpg| gr-thumb.jpg    | now     | people    |
  6  | leaf         | lea.jpg | leaf-thumb.jpg  | now     | nature    |
  7  | dog          | dog.jpg | dog-thumb.jpg   | now     | animal    |
```

In this case i need show the results like this:

```
   Gallery name --> Gallery Nature (4) <-- Number of  occurrences 
   Gallery name --> Gallery People (2) <-- Number of  occurrences 
   Gallery name --> Gallery Animal (1) <-- Number of  occurrences
```

being the name of the gallery must be obtained through the "canais" table and the number of occurrences  must come from the  "galerias" table based in the "categoria" column. Can anyone help me to solve it ?

Comment: Join `htd` and `categoria` and do a `group by`.

Comment: What's going on with rows 4 and 5? Are those actually duplicates that got assigned different ids, or are they in fact different records?

Comment: @evanv Sorry rows 4 and 5 are typos the 5 row have a diferent value for titulo column. Now fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below query will help you

```
SELECT a.nome AS gallery  ,COUNT(b.titulo)  AS photos 
FROM canais a INNER JOIN galerias b ON a.htd    = b.categoria 
GROUP BY a.nome
```